# Determine the largest interval $]\alpha,+\infty[$ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}<1$ for every $a,b \in ]\alpha,+\infty[$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, quadratics, real-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be two (strictly) positive real numbers (i.e., $a,b \in ]0,+\infty[$).

How to determine the largest interval $]\alpha,+\infty[$ (that is contained in $]0,+\infty[$) such that $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}<1$$ for every $a,b \in ]\alpha,+\infty[$?

Obviously, $]\alpha,+\infty[$ is contained in $]2,+\infty[$.

Comment: *Hint:* Consider the case $a=b$ first.

Comment: @MartinR $\alpha=2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ the interval is $]2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},+\infty[$.

Comment: That looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a=b=x$ such that

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac 2 x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2}}=1 \iff 2+\frac1{\sqrt 2}=x$$

Now observe that

$$f(a,b)=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

is decresing with $a$ and $b$ therefore $\alpha=2+\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: I am fairly sure that $\alpha=2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (as already obtained by OP in a comment) is the correct result.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I check that.